# Registros repetidos MySQL

Tags: mysql

necesito su ayuda para resolver lo siguiente; tengo una tabla:

```
id / id_pac / descrpcion
1     001        diabetes
2     002        gripa
3     002        gripa
4     003        dolor 
5     003        dolor
```

En esta tabla se registran las enfermedades encontradas en los pacientes pacientes, sin embargo un paciente no puede tener dos veces gripa o tres veces dolor.

Lo que necesito es borrar los registros duplicados dejando solo una enfermedad para cada paciente

Es decir que de la tabla anterior lo que necesito obtener es:

```
id / id_pac / descrpcion
1     001        diabetes
2     002        gripa
4     003        dolor
```

Gracias por su apoyo !!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo? podes mostrar lo que probaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        GROUP BY id_pac, descrpcion


    Solución.

     1. Visita el sitio:
    http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/examples/GUI/ .

     2. Crear tabla.

    CREATE TABLE my_table (
        id integer,
        id_pac integer,
        descrpcion text
    );

    3. Mostrar tablas.

      SELECT `name`
      FROM `sqlite_master`
      WHERE type='table';

    ======================= 
    name        
    -----------------------
    my_table    
    ======================= 

        4. Ingrese valores
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,'001','diabetes');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2,'002','gripa');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3,'002','gripa');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (4,'003','dolor');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (5,'003','dolor');

5. Mostrar tabla

Select * from my_table

======================= 
id  id_pac  descrpcion
-----------------------
1   001     diabetes
2   002     gripa
3   002     gripa
4   003     dolor
5   003     dolor
======================= 

6. Aquí comienza la solución. 

quieres agrupar por id_pac y descrpcion

        SELECT
        id, 
        id_pac, 
        descrpcion

        FROM 
        my_table

        GROUP BY id_pac, descrpcion

======================= 
id  id_pac  descrpcion
-----------------------
1   001     diabetes
2   002     gripa
4   003     dolor
======================= 

7. Se quiser descrpcion unico 

        SELECT
        id, 
        id_pac, 
        descrpcion

        FROM 
        my_table

        GROUP BY id_pac, descrpcion

        HAVING COUNT(*)  = 1

======================= 
id  id_pac  descrpcion
-----------------------
1   001     diabetes
======================= 

8. Si quieres una descripción duplicada
        SELECT
        id, 
        id_pac, 
        descrpcion

        FROM 
        my_table

        GROUP BY id_pac, descrpcion

        HAVING COUNT(*)  > 1

======================= 
id  id_pac  descrpcion
-----------------------
2   002     gripa
4   003     dolor
=======================
```

Comment: Bienvenido Rubén, además del código no estaría de más argumentar tu respuesta y darle valor añadido, puesto que no explicas realmente la solución a la pregunta.

Comment: Hola!! gracias por tomarte el tiempo. por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Tene en cuenta que la pregunta fue cerrada, y como tal, no se puede aceptar una respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben lo estoy empleando en mi Query.